# LC oscillator RFC value

Tags: oscillator

So I designed this oscillator, somewhat loosely; I was unable to find a way to calculate the inductor at the collector (RFC) so I just guessed a value. The oscillations seem to be rather stable. What can I do to determine the RFC more systematically? Any other recommendations for this design would be appreciated. The oscillations are around 1MHz.

I purposely hid the values so the rats from my university, also doing this project, don't get cute.

[image]

Comment: Your oscillator has an output which delivers no power (a load resistor is missing). So it oscillates easily. Tim's and Andy's suggestions might be modified (they use L2's reactance as a guide) once a load resistor is added to Q1's collector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to choose a value for L1 that's between 4x and 10x the value of L2, and don't go for a terrifically high Q at your tank's resonant frequency.  You want a coil prevents the power supply from interfering with the tank operation, but if you get too enthusiastic then L1 will find a capacitor (or combination thereof) to resonate with and whatever resonant pole pair it and that capacitance forms will also resonate.  This will probably take the form of "squegging", where the oscillator starts and stops rapidly, at a rate depending on the value of L1 and other circuit elements.

Answer (score 0):

> *What can I do to determine the RFC more systematically?*

Take the RFC down in value progressively until things start going pear-shaped in terms of frequency increasing and distortion getting worse or the oscillator stopping working. Generally, a good rule of thumb for the common-emitter Colpitts oscillator is make the RFC at least ten times the main tuning inductor value.

> *Any other recommendations*

I'm not a big fan of C5 (the emitter capacitor) so I'd be considering setting the amplitude without using that component. Of course, it will start a lot more quickly with it but there'll be more distortion in the sine shape.

You might also want to check at what DC voltage it works down to - you might want to ensure it still works at 5 volts for instance.

BTW - the component values shown mean it will oscillate around 1 MHz.

Answer (score 0):

"*What can I do to determine the RFC more systematically?* "

The systematic approach for designing this oscillator is as follows:

- Start with the oscillation condition: Unity loop gain at the desired frequency wo.
- Open the feedback loop at a suitable point - for example, after C3. Terminate the opening properly (with the approximate input resistance at the base node).
- Find the transfer function for the open loop (loop gain LG, by calculation or simulation) and set LG(jw=jwo)=1 (that means: Real function with magnitude "1").
- Solve for wo (formula for designing the circuit as desired).
- Find the (real) transfer function for w=wo and select the gain stage components (preferrably without C5) for a loop gain LG(w=wo)=1.1....1.5. This will ensure a safe start of oscillations.

**Comment** (hint):

My recommendation for finding the loop gain function: Consider the frequency dependent feedback circuit as a 3-rd-order lowpass in classical ladder structure: r_out-C1-L2-(C2||r_in) with r-out and r_in being the small-signal outout and input resistances of the gain stage, respectively.